# Will AC switch work for DC

Tags: switches

I have a on-off switch that'll use for a kill switch for my car using the gas pump. The switch says 6A/125V 3A/250V 22 AWG.
For my purpose it needs to handle 12V 20 Amps max.

Comment: Note that the answers in the other question say: DC specs are typically much lower than AC for the same switch. Than was repeated a couple of times there and it won't hurt to repeat it here.

Comment: Will a 6A switch work for 20A? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a 6A switch with a 20A load.  You may also run into issues with lower voltage rating at DC, but that hardly matters as you are already so far beyond the current rating.